# Highlighting using distinct color where features overlap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, overlapping-features, color

I have two species on my map and right now they are different colors. However, what I want to happen is when they overlap in the same spot, the color is a distinct difference from the other two colors. Only thing I've thought of is to change the transparency so the colors mix together. I'm using the stable version of GQIS.

Do you know a better way?

Comment: Have you looked in the options "heatmap" and "point displacement" in the style tab of your layer?

Comment: Or, you may want to play with `Feature blending mode` in the *Style | Layer rendering*.

Comment: You should look this post: http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/

Answer (score 1):

Set the layers atop of each other and set them to something like multiply or sustract as blending mode